# json response of mysql fetch data

Tags: php, mysql, json

```
$sql=mysql_query("select * from school");
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
print_r($rows)."<br/>";
$response=array();
$info=array();
foreach($rows as $row)
{      
    $schoolInfo=array();
    $schoolInfo["schoolid"]=$row["schoolid"];
    $schoolInfo["schoolname"]=$row["schoolname"];
    //$schoolInfo ["grade"] = $row["grade"];
    array_push($info,$schoolInfo);    
}
$response['info']=$info;
echo json_encode($response);
```

here i am getting blank ouput of $response. i am using php script for fetch data from mysql but i am getting blank output...

Comment: Did you connect to mysql? did you select your db? the code loop seems to be right, probably the problem is in your mysql connection..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the code something as below. SO it will loop the data using `while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))` and generate the array for JSON. 
NOTE : Make sure that the code is connecting to mysql and selecting correct database before executing the query.

```
$sql=mysql_query("select * from school");
$response=array();
$info=array();
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){      
    $schoolInfo=array();
    $schoolInfo["schoolid"]=$rows["schoolid"];
    $schoolInfo["schoolname"]=$rows["schoolname"];
    //$schoolInfo ["grade"] = $rows["grade"];
    array_push($info,$schoolInfo);    
}
$response['info']=$info;
echo json_encode($response);
```